# Regex in Java Pattern on multine

Tags: java, regex

Content of file display.props, loaded via .xml

```
Xvfb Display Properties
Wed Jul 27 18:31:50 CEST 2016
DISPLAY=\:20
XAUTHORITY=/tmp/Xvfb4443942380574278711.Xauthority
```

Now I want to read this file and get the disply number (20)

```
    String xvfbPropsFile = System.getProperty("display.props");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DISPLAY.*([0-9][0-9])",
            Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(xvfbPropsFile);
```

However this match and all the others that I tried do not work, any ideas?

Comment: The display number can be one digit, and `.*` is greedy.  Try `DISPLAY.*?(\d+)` to make the `.*` stop as soon as a digit is encountered.

Comment: Remove `Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL`

Comment: The description *do not work* is not appropriate. You should have mentioned you get the last 2 digits in the string. You actually need to get the first two digits after DISPLAY. All you need is `"DISPLAY.*?([0-9][0-9])"`. The MULTILINE modifier is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regex with `String#replaceALl()` ==> `replaceAll("(?s).*DISPLAY=.*?(\\d+).*", "$1")`

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s).*DISPLAY=.*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
```

O/P :

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems on your code, first one you are using a greedy operator with flag DOTALL, so you will match a different string than you want (`11` instead `20`). You can solve this by using an ungreedy operator `.*?` or just remove the DOTALL flag.

Additionally the 2nd problem is that you have to grab the captured content from capturing groups with `m.group(1)`:

```
String xvfbPropsFile = "Xvfb Display Properties\n" +
                            "Wed Jul 27 18:31:50 CEST 2016\n" +
                            "DISPLAY=\\:20\n" +
                            "XAUTHORITY=/tmp/Xvfb4443942380574278711.Xauthority";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DISPLAY.*([0-9][0-9])");
Matcher m=p.matcher(xvfbPropsFile);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // group 1 contains 20
}
```

**[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/0PDF2K)**